# Miller-Rabin Primality test FIPS 186-3 implementation

Tags: c++, math, implementation, primality-test

Im trying to implement the Miller-Rabin primality test according to the description in [FIPS 186-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf) C.3.1. No matter what I do, I cannot get it to work. The instructions are pretty specific, and I dont think I missed anything, and yet Im getting `true` for non-prime values.

What did I do wrong?

```
template <typename R, typename S, typename T>
T POW(R base, S exponent, const T mod){
    T result = 1;
    while (exponent){
        if (exponent & 1)
            result = (result * base) % mod;
        exponent >>= 1;
        base = (base * base) % mod;
    }
    return result;
}



// used uint64_t to prevent overflow, but only testing with small numbers for now
bool MillerRabin_FIPS186(uint64_t w, unsigned int iterations = 50){
    srand(time(0));
    unsigned int a = 0;
    uint64_t W = w - 1; // dont want to keep calculating w - 1
    uint64_t m = W;
    while (!(m & 1)){
        m >>= 1;
        a++;
    }

    // skipped getting wlen
    // when i had this function using my custom arbitrary precision integer class,
    // and could get len(w), getting it and using it in an actual RBG 
    // made no difference 

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
        uint64_t b = (rand() % (W - 3)) + 2; // 2 <= b <= w - 2
        uint64_t z = POW(b, m, w);
        if ((z == 1) || (z == W))
            continue;
        else
            for(unsigned int j = 1; j < a; j++){
                z = POW(z, 2, w);
                if (z == W)
                    continue;
                if (z == 1)
                    return 0;// Composite
            }
    }
    return 1;// Probably Prime
}
```

this:

```
std::cout << MillerRabin_FIPS186(33) << std::endl;
std::cout << MillerRabin_FIPS186(35) << std::endl;
std::cout << MillerRabin_FIPS186(37) << std::endl;
std::cout << MillerRabin_FIPS186(39) << std::endl;
std::cout << MillerRabin_FIPS186(45) << std::endl;
std::cout << MillerRabin_FIPS186(49) << std::endl;
```

is giving me:

```
0
1
1
1
0
1
```

Comment: Can we see `POW`? I see a mistake that could declare some primes as composite, but nothing jumps out for the other way round. For what values are you getting wrong results?

Comment: Where is your definition of POW?

Comment: pow is fine, but ill put it up in any case

Comment: BTW, your random numbers are [_not_ uniformly distributed](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35556/skewing-the-distribution-of-random-values-over-a-range) -- that modulo-operation skews the results.

Comment: What happens if `result * base` or `base * base` overflows?

Comment: they shouldnt, since the values are so small. also, normally, i would be using a custom arbitrary precision integer, so they wouldnt overflow. i just changed it to `uint64_t` to double check that the math in the custom class wasnt wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference between your implementation and Wikipedia's is that you forgot the second return composite statement. You should have a return 0 at the end of the loop.

Edit: As pointed out by Daniel, there is a second difference. The continue is continuing the inner loop, rather than the outer loop like it's supposed to.

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
    uint64_t b = (rand() % (W - 3)) + 2; // 2 <= b <= w - 2
    uint64_t z = POW(b, m, w);
    if ((z == 1) || (z == W))
        continue;
    else{
        int continueOuter = 0;
        for(unsigned int j = 1; j < a; j++){
            z = POW(z, 2, w);
            if (z == W)
                continueOuter = 1;
                break;
            if (z == 1)
                return 0;// Composite
        }
        if (continueOuter) {continue;}
    }
    return 0; //This is the line you're missing.
}
return 1;// Probably Prime
```

Also, if the input is even, it will always return probably prime since a is 0. You should add an extra check at the start for that.

Comment: One hopes a primality test isn't being used on even numbers. :)

Comment: Oh c'mon, this certainly doesn't deserve a _downvote_... it's a good point. :)

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a legitimate issue and I had no idea what numbers were being tested at the time I wrote that.

Comment: now im getting 0
0
0
0
0
0 and i added the `{}` to the else, so its not returning 0 after 1 iteration

Comment: @calccrypto: you can't just add the break *and* the return 0, because now whenever you break the return 0 is triggered.  Set a flag (say contloop) to false before the loop.  Instead of just break, set "contloop = 1; break;}, and then only return 0 if contloop is false.  [Or something.]

Answer (score 4):

In the inner loop,

```
        for(unsigned int j = 1; j < a; j++){
            z = POW(z, 2, w);
            if (z == W)
                continue;
            if (z == 1)
                return 0;// Composite
        }
```

you should `break;` instead of `continue;` when `z == W`. By `continue`ing, in the next iteration of that loop, if there is one, `z` will become 1 and the candidate is possibly wrongly declared composite. Here, that happens for 17, 41, 73, 89 and 97 among the primes less than 100.

Comment: Aargh, just as I was about to hit send, too.  I think both this and the return 0 if this loop makes it all the way through are necessary.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. The continue is only continuing the inner loop, not the outer loop like it's supposed to.